# Pass specific element to jsp from arraylist in model from servlet

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, arraylist

So to be more specific what Im trying to solve. How can I show the first element in my Arraylist:"sortedDomainList" in my jsp?

EDIT : Model and ArrayList working tried in normal java application.

**MODEL** short version.

```
    public ArrayList<String> sortedDomainList = new ArrayList<String>();



    public ArrayList<String> getSortedDomainList() {
        return sortedDomainList;
    }


    public void setSortedDomainList(ArrayList<String> sortedDomainList) {
        this.sortedDomainList = sortedDomainList;
    }
}
```

**CONTROLLER/SERVLET**

```
package com.comparebet.controller;

import com.comparebet.model.*;

@WebServlet("/Controller")
public class Controller extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public Controller() {
        super();

    }

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    }

     public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, ServletException {
            ArrayList<String> sortedDomainList = new BeanModel().getSortedDomainList();
            request.setAttribute("d", sortedDomainList);
            RequestDispatcher view = request.getRequestDispatcher("view.jsp");
            view.forward(request, response);
        }
    }
```

**VIEW/JSP**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>CompareBet</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/Comparebet" method="get" accept-charset="UTF-8"></form>
<h1>  ${d.sortedDomainList[0]}</h1>


</body>
</html>
```

This is my first try on MVC so I feel really lost when it comes down to servlet.

Comment: I tested now its work fine when I run it as an application so its is a jsp servlet problem.

Comment: Edits done. Ok I will try it tomorrow way to tired now. Just spent the last hours reading more about servlets and jsp still confused tho :) Some guys put code in jsp but some say strictly no to it.

Comment: When I request sortedDomainList does it execute all code in my Model?

Comment: System.out.println(sortedDomainList) nothing happens when I try this.

Comment: It works when I changed the to : http://localhost:8080/Comparebet/Comparebet/Controller instead of /Comparebet/Comparebet/*

Answer (score -1):

```
    <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>CompareBet</title>
</head>
<body>
<%
ArrayList<String> sortedDomainList= request.getAttribute("d");
for(String domain:sortedDomainList){
 %>
 <h1> <%= domain %> </h1>

<% } %>



</body>
</html>
```